# Google maps API is not using region hint

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having problems telling the Google maps API to restrict the results from the geocoding service to a specific region.

A simple example reproducing the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pqZGr/

The JavaScript code is really simple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term, 'region': 'it' }, function (results, status) {
                response($.map(results, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.formatted_address
                    }
                }));
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I also specified the API URL as `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?region=it&language=it&sensor=false` besides the `'region': 'it'` in the request.

The problem is the addresses returned by Google are not restricted (nor hinted) to Italy

For example if you search `mil` (the begininning of `Milano`) I get `Circondario di Miltenberg, Germania` and `Milion, Alemdar Mh., 34122 Istanbul/Provincia di Istanbul, Turchia` and `reka Mil', Sacha-Jacuzia, Russia`.

It's returning results (also, only three?) from all over the world, an nothing from Italy (even when there are multiple cities matching `mil`).

What am I doing wrong?

As a side note, is it possible to restrict the search only to the cities, and not to full addresses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you really should be using the Google Places Autocomplete API [standalone](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html) or [built in](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete) to the Google Maps API.

The geocoding service isn't designed for autocomplete queries, and won't return the kind of results you're looking for.  The region parameter is a hint like you said, but it's not a restriction so if there is no suitable "mil" in Italy, or there is a much better match elsewhere you'll get those results.

There's no way to restrict the results to just cities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google geocoder autocomplete with jQuery UI, you can edit one line in ui.geo_autocomplete.js, line 46, and add your region. It's not 100% precise, but will reduce the number of found addresses:

```
this.options._geocoder.geocode({'address': _address}, function(_results, _status)
```

Replace with:

```
this.options._geocoder.geocode({'address': _address + ' YOUR_REGION_HERE'}, function(_results, _status)
```